# Spring, JPA and Rest and Duplicate entry for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I'm just starting to learn Spring and JPA and I've run into a bit of a wall trying to figure out what is causing my app to try and insert cascaded values in multiple times. I have the following structure:

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>core</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>core</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Person.java

```
@Data
@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
@Table(name = "persons")
public class Person extends Auditable<String> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "user_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST} )
    @JoinColumn(name = "hometown_id")
    private City hometown;

    protected Person() {
    }

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName, City hometown) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.hometown = hometown;
    }
}
```

City.java

```
@Data
@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=false)
@Table(name = "cities")
public class City extends Auditable<String> {

    @Id
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "city_name", unique = true)
    private String cityName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "hometown", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private Set<Person> inhabitants = new HashSet<>(); 

    protected City() {}

    public City(String cityName) {
        this.cityName = cityName;
    }
}
```

My repositories:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(exported = false)
public interface CityRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<City, Long> {}

@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "people", path = "people")
public interface PersonRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Person, Long> {}
```

So, the first time I do the following:

```
REQUEST:

curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:8080/api/persons \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -d '{
    "firstName": John",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "hometown": {
        "cityName": "Los Angeles"
    }
}'

RESPONSE:

{
    "firstName": John",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "qualifications": "asdasdasdasd",
    "hometown": {},
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/persons/1"
        },
        "person": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/persons/1"
        }
    }
}
```

If I refresh the list from /api/persons, I see that the correct relationship exists.

```
{
    "firstName": John",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "qualifications": "asdasdasdasd",
    "hometown": {
        "_links": {
            "requisitions": {
                "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/requisitions/3"
            }
        }
    },
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/persons/1"
        },
        "person": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/persons/1"
        }
    }
}
```

But the second person I try and persist with the same hometown, an error is thrown:

```
REQUEST:

curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:8080/api/persons \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -d '{
    "firstName": Jane",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "hometown": {
        "cityName": "Los Angeles"
    }
}'

RESPONSE:

{
    "cause": {
        "cause": {
            "cause": null,
            "message": "Duplicate entry 'Los Angeles' for key 'PRIMARY'"
        },
        "message": "could not execute statement"
    },
    "message": "could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [PRIMARY]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement"
}
```

How do I configure the relationships to persist a new version ONLY if it doesn't already exist? I know I can do it by making multiple API calls to lookup/persist the city first, but thats way too many network hops to just save a small piece of data.

Side question, I have the fetchType set to EAGER on the hometown column, but I still only just get a link. Is there a way to make it pre-resolve the data before sending it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The relation seems weird to me but it's completely upto you, the reason for error you can see is self explanatory, you are trying to persist the same entity for different users while what you should be doing is persist many persons for the same city. Update your request and controller accordingly to something like this

```
curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:8080/api/persons \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -d '{
    "cityName": "Los Angeles",
    "inhabitants": [
       {
        "firstName": John",
        "lastName": "Doe",
       "qualifications": "asdasdasdasd"
       },
       {
        "firstName": Jane",
        "lastName": "Doe",
       }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Im trying to use city as more of a central lookup table rather than the main relationship. If for example I added a homeState property to persons, this answer no longer works. Is there a way I can do the cascase manually somehow and do a lookup first?

Answer (score 0):

can you try without constructors? I use the same type of code, and Lombok @Data should make those parts useless :

```
protected City() {}

public City(String cityName) {
    this.cityName = cityName;
}

protected Person() {
}

public Person(String firstName, String lastName, City hometown) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.hometown = hometown;
}
```

Maybe it's not good for your project but I think you should make a request to get city from its name, then add a person to this city, using city ID, not cityname, because in your model, cityname is an ID.

Comment: The constrictors are just there to help with filling in some test data. The app behaves the same way regardless.

As for the requests...it really shouldn't have to be up to the UI to understand the server data implementation, nor have to pass that data back and forth. I'm thinking I may have to write a custom controller that does this lookup for me and not rely on the built in CRUD repos from spring.